# How to set the value in hashmap key:value pair conditionally?

Tags: grails, hashmap

I'am using grails.
I want to set the values in map conditionally.
For Eg:

```
HashMap<String, String> mymap= new HashMap<String, String>();
    if (author != null){
        mymap['TITLE'] = book.title
    }else{
        mymap['TITLE'] = 'NA'
    }
```

So, what I want to acheive is, I want to set the value of my title as "book.title" if the particular value is not null otherwise it should be a normal string "NA".

**Output I'am Getting**

```
mymap:[TITLE: NA]
```

**Output I want**

```
mymap:[TITLE: [TITLE1, TITLE2, NA, TITLE4, TITLE5]]
```

*Something like this*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using groovy all of this can be done more elegantly:

You must be getting iteration of book from somewhere ?

Change this from:

```
HashMap<String, String> mymap= new HashMap<String, String>();
    if (author != null){
        mymap['TITLE'] = book.title
    }else{
        mymap['TITLE'] = 'NA'
    }
```

to:

```
List titles=[]
books?.title?.each { title->
    titles<< (title?:'NA')
}
def mymap=['TITLE':titles]
```

Comment: Worked Brilliantly......! :) 
But, is there any way that I could avoid the null values in my list?
For eg I am getting this output: 
[title1, title2, NA, null, NA, null]
How can I replace 'null' by 'NA' ?

Comment: sounds like those nulls may not be nulls as in actual groovy nulls since  `titles<< (title?:'NA')` is doing exactly that so maybe replace this with `if (!title||title!='null') { titles << title }` I have a feeling those nulls are not real nulls

Comment: `each` is for sideeffects.  use `collect` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use  this instead :

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
 if (author != null){
    myList.add(book.title)
}else{
    myList.add('NA')    
}
map.put("TITLE",myList) ;
```

Comment: Not working. My list is still showing me null values.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter variant:

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> map = [:].withDefault{ [] }
map[ 'TITLE' ] << ( author ? book.title : 'NA' )
```